# sorting publication list

Tags: biblatex, sorting

I am trying to sort my publication list with year and month to differentiate publications from the same year. I am kind of struggling to get this right. I used one of your implementation and i manage to split in various subsection the right items calling my own .bib file but the sorting in each subsection is wrong. any help?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
%\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
%\usepackage[french]{babel}
\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amsmath, amssymb}
\usepackage[backend=biber,sorting=ndymdt,style=phys]{biblatex}

\DeclareFieldFormat{labelnumberwidth}{}
\setlength{\biblabelsep}{0pt}

\DeclareSortingScheme{ndymdt}{
    \sort{
        \field{presort}
    }
    \sort[final]{
        \field{sortkey}
    }
    \sort{
        \name{sortname}
        \name{author}
        \name{editor}
        \name{translator}
        \field{sorttitle}
        \field{title}
    }
    \sort[direction=descending]{
        \field{sortyear}
        \field{year}
        \literal{9999}
    }
    \sort[direction=descending]{
        \field[padside=left,padwidth=2,padchar=0]{month}
        \literal{99}
    }
    \sort[direction=descending]{
        \field[padside=left,padwidth=2,padchar=0]{day}
        \literal{99}
    }
    \sort{
        \field{sorttitle}
    }
    \sort[direction=descending]{
        \field[padside=left,padwidth=4,padchar=0]{volume}
        \literal{9999}
    }
}

\addbibresource{mybiblio2016.bib}

\begin{document}
    \nocite{*}
    \printbibliography[type=article,title={Journal articles}]
    \printbibliography[type=inproceedings,title={Conference papers}]
    \printbibliography[type=book,title={Books chapters}]
    \printbibliography[type=unpublished,title={Presentations}]
    \printbibliography[type=misc,title={Invited talks}]
    \printbibliography[type=artwork,title={Posters}]
    \printbibliography[type=report,title={Technical notes}]
    \printbibliography[type=thesis,title={Thesis}]
    \printbibliography[type=patent,title={Patents}]
\end{document}
```

Comment: Without the `.bib` file we cannot really test your MWE. And from your description it is not entirely clear to me what exactly is wrong? But maybe the option `defernumbers=true` can help you. Note that you will have to delete the temporary `.aux`, `.bcf` and `.bbl` files before you re-compile for a change in this option to take effect.

Comment: Dear Moewe, I tried your recommendation but not much progress. I just want my references to be sorted by year and month in descending order from 2015 to 2001  for each susbections. here is a link to the bib file. hope somebody can help. https://www.dropbox.com/s/zcww0t2bbr6f6cg/mybiblio2016.bib?dl=0

Comment: Do you want to sort by year and month only and ignore the names? Because currently you are sorting by names, then year and month. Your `.bib` file is quite massive, so I'm not sure where to focus on exactly.

Comment: just year then month. for instance i have a few articles all in 2015 I want them to appear in the proper descending order. no need to sort names they appear as entered in the .bib. in My bib exported via zotero each item is labelled as article, inproceeding. I got the item in the proper subsection (jouranl article, conference...) but I missing the date sorting. appreciate your help.

Comment: Mhh, what I'm asking is should "Aaardvark 2010" be sorted before or after "Zoingbert 2015"? Currently from what I can see works are ordered by the author first and then (if all authors are the same) the year comes into play, which from what I can see is not too often.

Comment: So you want to sort by year and month first, right? What if there is a tie (i.e. you have two works written in the same year and month), does the author or the title decide who goes first?

Comment: yes exactly ,  regardless of authors name, some article are published for instance in november 2015 and another one in september 2015. So i d like to have the one of november 2015 (the most recent) to appear on top before the one of september 2015. 2 in same month is very unlikely in my field...but day could be the discriminator

Comment: OK, have a look at my answer, please. Please note that your `.bib` file contains some problems: some names in the `author` field are not right, the correct format is to separate multiple authors with the `and` keyword and not with commas (or even semicolons), you also need to leave a space after the initial before the family name. In particular I'm talking about `i.samad_m.boutchich_d.sinha_ta.coombs_resonant_2007`, `i.haneef_selective_2007`, `michiel_van_duuren;_nader_akil;_karen_attenborough;_mohamed_boutchich;_dusan_golubovic_embedded_2008`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The sorting `ndymdt` in your MWE sorts first by name (`sortname`, `author`, `editor` etc.), then by year, month and day, and then by title.
So  you might get

> Aaardvark 2010
>
> Banana 2011
>
> Bar 2009
>
> Foo 2009
>
> Zoidberg 2015

If you want to sort by date first and then by name and finally by title to get

> Zoidberg 2015
>
> Banana 2011
>
> Aaardvark 2010
>
> Bar 2009
>
> Foo 2009

you need

```
\DeclareSortingScheme{ddatent}{
  \sort{
    \field{presort}
  }
  \sort[final]{
    \field{sortkey}
  }
  \sort[direction=descending]{
    \field[strside=left,strwidth=4]{sortyear}
    \field[strside=left,strwidth=4]{year}
    \literal{9999}
  }
  \sort[direction=descending]{
    \field[padside=left,padwidth=2,padchar=0]{month}
    \literal{00}
  }
  \sort[direction=descending]{
    \field[padside=left,padwidth=2,padchar=0]{day}
    \literal{00}
  }
  \sort[direction=descending]{
    \field[padside=left,padwidth=4,padchar=0]{volume}
    \literal{9999}
  }
  \sort{
    \name{sortname}
    \name{author}
    \name{editor}
    \name{translator}
    \field{sorttitle}
    \field{title}
  }
  \sort{
    \field{sorttitle}
    \field{title}
  }
}
```

which you use with `sorting=ddatent`.

Comment: looks great , really appreciate, so now i can use with any style right?

Comment: @user97118 That should be possible, yes.